# Excel - Hyperlink to a worksheet which name is found in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have an Excel file with about 40 worksheets, and on the first sheet, I have a list of the names of all the other sheets (so 39 names — from `B4:B42`).

On the first sheet, in the cells on the right of the 39 names, I want to create hyperlinks so that when I click on one of the links (or cells containing links), it automatically brings me to the worksheet which name is on the left of that cell.
So right now, my hyperlink function for the 1st name is:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'name_of_the_worksheet'!A1";B4)
```

It works but in the `name_of_the_worksheet` part of the function, I have to write all the 39 names one by one which takes time. Is there an easier way?

(I tried `=HYPERLINK("#'B4'!A1";B4)` but it didn't work.)

Comment: Sounds like you want [this](https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-generate-a-list-of-sheet-names-from-a-workbook-without-vba/)

Comment: it worked! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `CONCATENATE()` for concatenating (join) your strings:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#", B4, "!A1"), B4)
```

or — which is the same — the concatenation operator `&`:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & B4 & "!A1", B4)
```

(Put this formula into the cell `C4` and then, of course, copy it to the remaining block `C5:C42`.)

---

An alternative solution:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#", ADDRESS(1, 1, , , B4)), B4)
```

or — with operator `&` instead of the `CONCATENATE()` function —

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(1, 1, , , B4), B4)
```

---

**The explanation of the alternative solution:**

Suppose the contents of your cell `B4` is `Sheet2`.

The function `ADDRESS()` in the form

```
ADDRESS(1, 1, , , B4)
```

(the 3rd and 4th parameters are omitted because their default values are O.K.)
returns as a result the string `"Sheet2!A1"`

It is the string of the address of the cell in row `1` and column `1`( i.e. of the cell `A1`) of the sheet given in the cell `B4` (i.e. string `Sheet2`).

Then the function `CONCATENATE` in the form

```
CONCATENATE("#", ADDRESS(1,1,,,B4))
```

puts the symbol `#` in front of it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first solution and it didn't work, I got an error message saying "reference isn't valid" but the 2nd one worked :)

Comment: You probably forgot put exclamation mark in the string `"!A1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if the sheet name has a space in it then this displays and error however if you make sure you use underscores it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell you want linked.
Select LINK att he bottom of the menu.
Select PLACE IN THIS DOCUMENT in the left column.
Select the page in the centre of the window.

Comment: But this requires 156 steps — the four steps you describe, repeated manually for each of the 39 sheets! If I’m misunderstanding your answer, please [edit] it to make it clearer and more complete.